# How to pass user credentials through Wapiti Web Application Vulnerability Scanner

Tags: penetration-testing, wapiti

I would like to test our web application with the [Wapiti](http://www.ict-romulus.eu/web/wapiti/home) scanner.  In my scenario, I am assuming the attacker would be an authenticated user.  How do I configure Wapiti to use a specific username and password on our login form so I can test the pages behind it?

Note: this is not http or domain based authentication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `wapiti-getcookie` first to collect the cookies associated with logging in. These typically get collected to a file, which can then be passed on subsequent runs to `wapiti`.

The following is verbatim from the Wapiti example on the site.

#### Example

First, I use `wapiti-getcookie` to login in the restricted area and get the cookie in `cookies.json`:

```
$ python bin/wapiti-getcookie /tmp/cookies.json http://127.0.0.1/vuln/login.php
<Cookie PHPSESSID=OLPNLIEBPEFELBIFGMKJEKOD for 127.0.0.1/>
Please enter values for the following form: 
url = http://127.0.0.1/vuln/login.php
username (default) : admin
password (letmein) : secret
<Cookie PHPSESSID=OLPNLIEBPEFELBIFGMKJEKOD for 127.0.0.1/>
```

It can also be done with wapiti-cookie this way:

```
$ python bin/wapiti-cookie /tmp/cookies.json \
       http://127.0.0.1/vuln/login.php username=admin password=secret
```

Then, I scan the vulnerable website using the cookie and excluding the logout script:

```
$ wapiti http://127.0.0.1/vuln/ -c cookies.json -x http://127.0.0.1/vuln/logout.php
```

#### References

[Wapiti Example](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/example.txt)

Comment: So, is not possible specify a cookie directly on a oneliner command ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cookie.py or getcookie.py script from Wapiti to authenticate and save the cookies.

If you're on Ubuntu, look in `/usr/share/wapiti` for these files.

Once you have the cookies saved somewhere, you can pass them to Wapiti as an option with `-c /path/to/cookie`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how to actually do this? Commands to run, etc?