# Using Wapiti on ASP login forms

Tags: asp.net, wapiti

Currently I'm trying to scan a web application with Wapiti. I was only curious if it is possible to use Wapiti on ASP login forms. I tried something like described on the following question.

[How to pass user credentials through Wapiti Web Application Vulnerability Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584524/how-to-pass-user-credentials-through-wapiti-web-application-vulnerability-scanne)

When trying to use getcookie it says 'Error getting URL'. Does Wapiti support ASP login forms or not?

I also tried exporting a cookie file in xml format but this seems to have no effect when using it.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the latest wapiti verion 2.3.0 http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/
and run the below command C:\Security\Wapiti\wapiti-2.3.0-win32-standalone>wapiti-cookie.exe cookies.json https://mywebsite.net -auth=username%pwd